# Problems with cross platform tell / seek in Python

Tags: python, linux, windows, cross-platform

Having a weird bug with Python 2.7.3 file reading. If I do this sort of thing:

```
end_of_header = f.tell()
print f.readline()
f.seek(end_of_header)
print f.readline()
```

the results are different. The file was written in Linux / Mac (not sure) and I'm trying to run it on Windows 7. If I run it in Linux it works. I have tried opening the file with both 'b' and 'U' tags and its not working. I have tried various encodings by opening with the codecs module.

Is the readline() causing the problem?

Some context is that there is a header after which there are a long trajectory (can be in the GB range) I need to be able read the header and process it, then read the file one line at a time. I may need to go back to the start of the file  (end of the header) at any time though.

Comment: Please provide info on what exactly is different in the results?

Comment: Try opening the file is text mode -- i.e. `mode='rt'`. Also, how does the value of `end_of_header` differ between the two platforms?

Answer (score 0):

As you say of Windows and Linux/Mac , I think you have
a problem of different **newlines** ( http://www.editpadpro.com/tricklinebreak.html )
used by the operating system in which the file was written and the one in which it is read.

And the problem arises because you opened the file in a not-binary mode.

Try to open the file in binary mode, that is to say with `'rb'` or `'rb+'` or `'ab'` or `'ab+'` according what you want to do.